# Load objects from text files into datastore/ndb using djangoappengine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to port my existing webapp2 to django. I'm using the djangoappengine that uses django 1.5

Previously while using webapp2, I used a URL handler to load a objects into the ndb

```
#webapp2
class MigrateData(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        listOfEntities=[]
        self.loadTagTrend("tagTrend_refine.txt",listOfEntities)
        ndb.put_multi(listOfEntities)

    def loadTagTrend(self, fileName, listOfData):
        f = open(fileName)
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        for line in lines:
                temp = line.strip().split("\t")
                data = models.TagTrend_refine(
                tag = temp[0],
                trendData = temp[1]
                )
        listOfData.append(data)
    return

   application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([("/migratedata", MigrateData),],debug=True)
```

How do I perform the same thing on django? Is it possible to run from the remote shell instead of using a url handler?

To keep it simple, I wish to find a method to run a .py script that does the reading of files and using bulk_create to save into the ndb on both deployed and development server.